# modular arithmetic over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Correct me if I am wrong here, but I just had a couple of questions that I wanted to make sure were right. First, consider $\mathbb{F}_{9} = \mathbb{F}_{3}[x] / (x^2 + 1)\mathbb{F}_{3}[x].$

1. Would the remainders for this case be $0, 1, x, x+1, 2, 2x, 2+x, 2+2x, 2x+1, 2x+x$?
2. If my first question is correct, then would $2x + (2 + x) = 2 + 3x = 2?$

Note that I am representing $F$ as a field.

Comment: Yes to both questions, but of course in (1) we're talking about the equivalence clases $\;1+(x^2+1)\;,\;x+(x^2+1)\;$ , etc. in the quotient ring (which is a field)

Comment: There should be only $9$ elements. Your list has $10$.

Comment: Ahh yes Andre. Good call. Is one of them a duplicate?

Comment: $\;2x+x=0\;$ in your field...

Comment: Why don't you write down the elements in some more or less elementary order, beginning with the elements of the prime field? $$\Bbb F_9=\{0,1,2,x,x+1,x+2,2x,2x+1,2x+2\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is much appreciated!. I think that I understand this problem now. I also know that multiplication has to be taken a little more carefully. If I had $(2x+2)(2x+1)$ what would my answer be then? It factors out to be $4x^2 + 6x + 2$. And then $x^2$ is just $1$ right? $6x$ is zero, and $2$ is $2$.

Comment: Well @SteveThomas: since you're dividing by the ideal $\,(x^2+1)\;$, in the quotient we actually have $\;x^2=-1=2\pmod 3\;$ , so $$(2x+2)(2x+1)=4x^2+6x+2=1\cdot (2)+0+2=1$$ Everything, of course, modulo three.

Answer (score 1):

In part 1 you have a duplicate: $2x+x = 0$. A more systematic way of listing them (polynomials over $F_3$ of degree < 2) would reveal this.

In part 2, yes: $3x = 0$.

Comment: I think I only listed $2+2x$. Did you mean that $2+2x = 2x+x$?

Comment: No, I misread the last entry! See above.